# Codeception - attachFile for input type that is set to display:none

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, codeception

I'm trying to upload a file using `$I->attachFile` command but it doesn't work when the input type is hidden. Is there a way that instead of using the input tag, I'll use the button instead? The button triggers the input after uploading.

```
<div id="action_buttons" class="col-md-5">
    <button id="front-btn-computer-uploader" class="btn btn-block btn-primary upload-from-computer">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span>
        <span class="upload-comp"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="upload-widget-container display-none">
        <div class="upload-widget-wrapper">
            <div class="upload-widget-status"></div>
            <input class="upload-widget-file" type="file" name="file">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried, and what the result was... any error messages, etc. It's also very important to include any relevant HTML and properly format the HTML and code.

Comment: It seems that this issue only occurs in firefox browser. When i tried this with chrome it works. For temporary fix, i just change the display:none to visible so i could also upload a file using firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use (according to [doc](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser#fillField))

```
$I->fillField("//input[ * `type='text']",`  "Hello World!");
$I->fillField(['name' => 'email'], 'jon * `mail.com');`
```

But instead of sending text "Hello world", try to insert full file path with the file name to the input. This will trigger form to upload the file.

Example:

```
$I->fillField("//input[@type='file']", "/home/user/document.txt");
```

Second solution, is to make the input visible (if you want to use attachFile method), so you will be able to operate with it.

Comment: Actually, I tried the second solution and it works, but it's just a hack. When i tried this with chrome browser. it works without making the element visible.

Comment: BTW, i tried the 1st solution you gave me, still doesn't work. it just shows this error:

Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'MNL-PCS-14-027', ip: '172.16.13.67', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown